# typescript model to json - Ignore null value property

Tags: jquery, json, angular, typescript

In angular 4 App,
My typescript Model,

```
export class Person{
  fname:string,
  lname?:string
}
```

lname is optional. Fill the model like below in the component

```
//Query form data
var people = form.get('people');

let model = new Person(){
  fname: people.get('firstname'),
  lname: people.get('lastname')
}
```

At this scenario, if i try to convert my model to json, when user doesn't enter value for lastname. My json output will look like below,

```
 {'fname': 'xyz', 'lname': null}
```

**Expected Result:**

But I want to eliminate all the null value properties in my json. So I am expecting

```
 {'fname':'xyz'}
```

but when user enters value at lname. the json should like below

```
{'fname':'xyx', 'lname': 'abc'}
```

How can i produce this json result from typescript model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the content of the lastname property of your form before inserting the value. Don't insert a value if it's not a string, assuming that's what that property contains.

Like this:

```
//Query form data
var people = form.get('people');

const model = new Person();
model.fname = people.get('firstname');
if (typeof people.get('lastname') === 'string') {
  model.lname = people.get('lastname');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple fix

Answer (score 1):

I've created a util lib for that. Maybe it can help.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-super-model

Using clean() function on instance that extends Model class will remove null, undefined and NaN.